# Using the Swift if let with logical AND operator &&

Tags: swift, expression

We know that we can use an `if let` statement as a shorthand to check for an optional nil then unwrap.

However, I want to combine that with another expression using the logical AND operator `&&`.

So, for example, here I do optional chaining to unwrap and optionally downcast my rootViewController to tabBarController. But rather than have nested if statements, I'd like to combine them.

```
if let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    if tabBarController.viewControllers.count > 0 {
        println("do stuff")
     }
 }
```

Combined giving:

```
if let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController &&
    tabBarController.viewControllers.count > 0 {
        println("do stuff")
     }
}
```

The above gives the compilation error **Use of unresolved identifier 'tabBarController'**

Simplifying:

```
if let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController && true {
   println("do stuff")
}
```

This gives a compilation error **Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type**. Having attempted various syntactic variations, each gives a different compiler error. I've yet to find the winning combination of order and parentheses.

**So, the question is, is it possible and if so what is correct syntax?**

*Note that I want to do this with an `if` statement **not** a `switch` statement or a ternary `?` operator.*

Comment: It is always a good idea to provide the error messages in the question.

Comment: More simple statement for people who like to experiment with this: `var foo : Int? = 10; if let bar = foo { if bar == 10 { println("Great success!") }}`

Comment: The error message when using `if let bar = foo && bar == 10` is `Use of unresolved identifier "bar"` (on the second `bar`, of course).

Comment: just a note that I was able to shorten the above example using Objective C's firstObject as follows: if let navigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers.bridgeToObjectiveC().firstObject as? UINavigationController {

Comment: 1. `bridgeToObjectiveC` is gone in beta 5 (and was quite possibly never intended for general use). 2. There's a `first` method on Swift's built-in `Array` type anyway.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

As of Swift 1.2, this ***is now possible***. The [Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3 beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22) state:

> **More powerful optional unwrapping with** if let — The if let construct
>   can now unwrap multiple optionals at once, as well as include
>   intervening boolean conditions. This lets you express conditional
>   control flow without unnecessary nesting.

With the statement above, the syntax would then be:

```
if let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController where tabBarController.viewControllers.count > 0 {
        println("do stuff")
}
```

This uses the `where` clause.

Another example, this time casting `AnyObject` to `Int`, unwrapping the optional, and checking that the unwrapped optional meets the condition:

```
if let w = width as? Int where w < 500
{
    println("success!")
}
```

***For those now using Swift 3, "where" has been replaced by a comma. The equivalent would therefore be:***

```
if let w = width as? Int, w < 500
{
    println("success!")
}
```

Comment: This should be come the chosen answer.

Comment: yes as it's now changed. Bryan's answer was correct at that time

Answer (score 65):

In **Swift 3** Max MacLeod's example would look like this:

```
if let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController, tabBarController.viewControllers.count > 0 {
    println("do stuff")
}
```

The `where` was replaced by `,`

Comment: So , is for && what is there for || ?

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat logical OR doesn't make sense in this context. `if let` can only proceed if the optional successfully unwrapped and is assigned to the new variable name. If you said `OR <something else>` then you could easily bypass the whole purpose of the `if let`. For logical OR, just do a normal `if` and inside the body deal with the fact that the first object is still optional at that point (not unwrapped).

Answer (score 37):

Max's answer is correct and one way of doing this.  Notice though that when written this way:

`if let a = someOptional where someBool { }`

The `someOptional` expression will be resolved first.  If it fails then the `someBool` expression will not be evaluated (short-circuit evaluation, as you'd expect).

If you want to write this the other way around it can be done like so:

`if someBool, let a = someOptional { }`

In this case `someBool` is evaluated first, and only if it evaluates to true is the `someOptional` expression evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**, I will use,

```
let i = navigationController?.viewControllers.index(of: self)
if let index = i, index > 0, let parent = navigationController?.viewControllers[index-1] {
    // access parent
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible.

From [Swift grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/zzSummaryOfTheGrammar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH38-XID_1126)

> GRAMMAR OF AN IF STATEMENT
>
> if-statement → **if** ­if-condition­ code-block­ else-clause­opt­
>
> if-condition → expression­ | declaration­
>
> else-clause → **else**­ code-block­ | **else­** if-statement­
>
> The value of any condition in an if statement must have a type that conforms to the BooleanType protocol. The condition can also be an optional binding declaration, as discussed in Optional Binding

if-condition must be expression­ *or* declaration­. You can't have both expression and declaration.

`let foo = bar` is a declaration, it doesn't evaluate to a value that conforms to `BooleanType`. It declares a constant/variable `foo`.

Your original solution is good enough, it is much more readable then combining the conditions.

Comment: but surely "if let" - which is valid Swift syntax - is both an expression and a declaration?

Comment: @MaxMacLeod `let foo = bar` is declaration not expression. you can't do `let boolValue = (let foo = bar)`

Comment: ok but to quote the Swift guide, page 11, the example is: if let name = optionalName. optionalName must be an expression whereby if optionalName is not an optional, it evaluates to true. The second part of the statement then kicks in whereby the unwrapped optional is assigned to name. So, question is, if "optionalName is not an optional" is an expression, can it be expanded with a logical AND. Btw I think you are probably correct in that it cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController ,
               tabBarController.viewControllers?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                    println("do stuff")   
              }
    }
```