# Returning nil when there is no match or group index is too high

Tags: regex, swift, option-type

I have the following code (in Swift 1.2), which is heavily inspired by [this tutorial on regex expressions](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial) (in particular by the function `listGroups` from the there given [playground](http://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/iRegex-Playground-Xcode-6.3.zip)):

```
func groupMatch(pattern: String, string: String, groupIndex: Int) -> String? {
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)
    let range = NSMakeRange(0,count(string))
    let match: NSTextCheckingResult? = regex?.firstMatchInString(string, options: nil, range: range)
    let substring: String? = (string as NSString).substringWithRange(match!.rangeAtIndex(groupIndex))
    if groupIndex < match!.numberOfRanges {
        return substring
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The idea is that given a pattern, a string and a (positive) integer `n` the function returns the first substring matched by the `n`-th group, if it exists. For example,

```
let pat = "aa\\s*(\\d+)\\.(\\d\\d)"
let str = "aa     1234.56  aa 7.89"

let grp1cap = groupMatch(pat, str, 1) // yields "1234"
let grp2cap = groupMatch(pat, str, 2) // yields "56"
```

So far so good. However, the definition of `groupMatch` does not do what I expected. The following line

```
let grp3cap = groupMatch(pat, str, 3)
```

does not seem to evaluate to `nil`. I would like test whether there is a value or not, e.g. like so

```
func test(pat: String, str: String, idx: Int) -> String {
    if let cap = groupMatch(pat, str, idx) {
        return cap
    } else {
        return ("no capture")
    }
}
```

but `test(pat, str, 3)` does not return the "no capture" string. In fact, it returns nothing at all.

What is wrong with the above definition of `groupMatch`? How do I get the intended behaviour?

Comment: I might have totally missed it in your post, but what does `test(pat, str, 3)` return? It does not return `nil` neither does it return "no capture" but I can't find in your post what it does return

Comment: @milo526 it returns nothing at all ... (will edit this in my question), thanks.

Comment: I guess "Nothing" is an empty String, there is a definite difference between nothing and an empty string

Comment: no, I do not mean an empty string.

Comment: Wel... You have a function that returns an Optional String, so it will return either `nil` or a String (which could be empty). It must be either of those.

Comment: yes, that is what I had hoped, but something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to initialize a substring by accessing a non-existent group. Thus, there is an error before the `if` condition is executed. Return the substring inside `if`:

```
func groupMatch(pattern: String, string: String, groupIndex: Int) -> String? {
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)
    let range = NSMakeRange(0,count(string))
    let match: NSTextCheckingResult? = regex?.firstMatchInString(string, options: nil, range: range)

    if groupIndex < match!.numberOfRanges { // RIGHT BELOW \/
        return (string as NSString).substringWithRange(match!.rangeAtIndex(groupIndex))
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then, `println(grp3cap)` will print `nil` and `println(test(pat, str, 3))` will print `no capture`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to stribizhev's answer: the modified function `groupMatch` still does not do what the title of the post suggests: `groupMatch` gives an error in case there is no match at all. If we also want to return `nil` in that case we can do:

```
func groupMatch(pattern: String, string: String, groupIndex: Int) -> String? {
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)
    let range = NSMakeRange(0,count(string))
    if let match = regex?.firstMatchInString(string, options: nil, range: range) where groupIndex < match.numberOfRanges {
        return (string as NSString).substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(groupIndex))
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now, for example, also `test(pat,"",0)` yields the desired "no capture".

NB: The elegant optional unwrapping with the `where` clause I found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202770/using-the-swift-if-let-with-logical-and-operator).